# Symfony User getting disconencted on deployment

Tags: authentication, symfony, fosuserbundle

Deploying my application on my server, i have issues :
When i log my user manually it works fine, when i go to profile, edit, it works ! ! 
**BUT**

WHEN i go to a page non-handled by FOSUserBundle, my user is not logged in anymore ...

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), $providerKey, $user->getRoles());
$userProvider = new UserProvider($this->get('fos_user.user_manager'));       

$this->get("security.token_storage")->setToken($token);

$event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
$this->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);
```

But in local it's working ....

If you have any idea ... would be glad, thx !!

EDIT : 
 here is my security.yml

```
# app/config/security.yml

security:
  encoders:
    Canapey\UserBundle\Entity\User:  sha512

  role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_USER:        [ROLE_USER]
    # Un admin hérite des droits d'auteur et de modérateur
    ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_MODERATEUR]
    # On garde ce rôle superadmin, il nous resservira par la suite
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

  providers:
    main:
      id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

  firewalls:
    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false
    main:
      pattern:      ^/
      anonymous:    true
      provider:     main
      form_login:
        login_path: fos_user_security_login
        check_path: fos_user_security_check
        csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
        always_use_default_target_path : true
      logout:
        path:       fos_user_security_logout
        target:     /
      remember_me:
        secret:     "%secret%" # %secret% est un paramètre de parameter 
        always_remember_me: true


  access_control:
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Comment: FOSUserBundle doesn't really handle Security related thing. If your user is not logged in on certain pages, it may be because your firewall is configured too tightly. If you set a firewall only on `/admin` but not on `/ ` then, the `SecurityContext` won't be available.

Comment: I added my security.yml, there is a role defined for the "/".
Moreover, it works when i connect myself with fosuserbundle connection, i  stay connected wherever i go :/

Answer (score 0):

Shortly: get the path of your sessions in `config.yml`:

```
framework:
    ...
    session:
        ...
        save_path: ...
```

and make sure it's not changed / emptied during deploy.

## Details

Most deploy systems clean all work folders (e.g. `cache`, `tmp`, `sessions`) during deploy, or even use a release-based structure where the actual root is created from scratch each time and soft-linked to a `current` directory (see e.g. Capistrano: http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/structure/).

In these situations, sessions are destroyed during deploy so of course you get logged out.